# Shared mailbox and passwords

Tags: office365, exchange, sharing, shared-mailbox

I have users who have a shared mailbox, which generally works fine for our purposes. However, they've recently received files from an organisation that are sent as links, not as attachments. The security on these is tight, and requires the account to whom the link was sent to login with their Office365 account to access. No other credentials are accepted. Obviously, this causes a problem, since shared mailboxes don't have passwords. The power dynamic makes it impossible for them to require the files be attached rather than linked.

Is there any way around this, other than to turn the shared mailbox into a standard, licenced account (which causes other issues)?

Comment: Individual Mailboxes is the correct answer here. Without that, set up a Drop Box or One Drive account, and have the mailbox owner get the documents (not the links) and place these in the file sharing setup.

Comment: So these links are to (Enterprise) OneDrive I presume?

Comment: Yes, Enterprise OneDrive is correct.

Is there no way other than individual mailboxes? That option really isn't optimal.